# nsarray has the many urls, load on progressview

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

```
imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679341_266553bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2897/9391679341_26643bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9691679341_26643bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679341_26644bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679341_26643bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679341_26643bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679341_26643bcafa_b.png",@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679344_26643bcafa_b.png", nil ];
```

array have many URL's ,load on progressview

The complete array loads on a progress view

Comment: i found answer, thanks for supporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIProgressView *progressVieww = 
   [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
// configure the progress view and add it to 
 your UI

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *ipaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *idocumentsDir = [ipaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *idataPath = [idocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File"];
        NSLog(@"idataPath:%@",idataPath);

        //Create folder here
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:idataPath])
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:idataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
        }
        // Image Download here
        NSString *fileName = [idataPath stringByAppendingFormat:@".jpg"];
        NSLog(@"imagePathDOWNLOAD:%@",fileName);

        _imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_imgData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

        // now dispatch any UI updates back to the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [progressView setProgress: (CGFloat) (i + 1.0) / [array count] animated:YES];



            tempImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:_imgData];
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save temporarily then use NSUserDefaults and set your object which is your mutable array. So it will save locally to your disk